# Using foundation's dropdowns within angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, zurb-foundation

I want to display a dropdown within a table shown using ng-repeat. The dropdown is built using Foundation's dropdown.js stuff.

```
<tr ng-repeat="lead in leads | filter:filterText>
   <td>
        <input type="text" data-dropdown="dropdown-{[{lead.id}]}" 
         autocomplete="off"/>
    <ul id="dropdown-{[{lead.id}]}" class='f-dropdown' data-dropdown-content>
        <li>Dropdown List</li>
    </ul>
   </td>
</tr>
```

When I put the input + ul outside of the ng-repeat (minus the added lead.id to define the ID) it works fine, but when it's inside the ng-repeat Foundation throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'is_hover' of undefined
```

on line 46 when hovering over, line 53 when hover out, and line 31, when clicking of foundation.dropdown.js.

I'm 100% sure this has to do with the fact that Foundation gets initiated before the Angular.js app gets initiated. I'm temporarily working around this by adding data-dropdown-init manually to the dropdown input, but I don't think that's pretty.

Any direction would be welcome.

Here's a plunkr imitating the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/fyTcPX17Fkbe8hSlUMtb?p=preview

Comment: please, can you reproduce it in Fiddle/Plunker?

Comment: @MaximShoustin I've added the link in the question.

Comment: As an update, I've handled this problem by creating an angular directive that does pretty much the same thing. It still uses the Foundation styles, but no longer the JS. If you want the details I can add it as an answer.

Comment: Sure, if you feel good with this answer - add it

Answer (score 0):

One pretty easy solution is to use [Angular-Foundation](http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/) though it's fairly opinionated about how you implement things.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens since the foundation dropdown function initiates before the angular app initiates. The one workaround to prevent this error is add the HTML attribute after angular app started. Just modify

```
data-dropdown-content
```

to

```
ng-attr-data-dropdown-content="{{$index}}"
```

I had the same issue and this one solved it

Comment: Hey @Jassim do you have documentation for ng-attr?

Comment: @Simon : Please check the doc provided by angular https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation